# How to deserialze a binary file

Tags: c#, serialization, binary

I'm having some trouble figuring out how to deserialize a binary file. I mostly can't figure out how to use the second argument of SerializationInfo.GetValue(); - if I just put a type keyword there, it's invalid, and if I use the TypeCode, it's invalid as well. This is my current attempt (obviously it doesn't build).

```
        protected GroupMgr(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
        Groups = (Dictionary<int, Group>) info.GetValue("Groups", (Type) TypeCode.Object);
        Linker = (Dictionary<int, int>) info.GetValue("Linker", (Type) TypeCode.Object );
        }
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The second argument in SerializationInfo.GetValue is the object type:

```
        protected GroupMgr(SerializationInfo info, StreamingContext context) {
            Groups = (Dictionary<int, Group>) info.GetValue("Groups", typeof(Dictionary<int, Group>));
            Linker = (Dictionary<int, int>) info.GetValue("Linker", typeof(Dictionary<int, int>));
            }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
typeof(object)
```

or

```
instance.GetType()
```

where `instance` is an `object`. Of course, replace by the actual types in your case.

Answer (score 0):

Instantiate temporary variables:

```
Dictionary<int, Group> tmpDict = new Dictionary<int, Group>();
Dictionary<int, int> tmpLinker = new Dictionary<int, int>();
```

then in your lines below:

```
Groups = (Dictionary<int, Group>) info.GetValue("Groups", tmpDict.GetType());
Linker = (Dictionary<int, int>) info.GetValue("Linker", tmpLinker.GetType());
```

Hope this helps,
Best regards,
Tom.